# alias parameter not working

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to make it easier to use scp so I learned about alias today, and I am using it like this:

```
alias loudie-scp="scp -i keys/aws.pem $1 ec2-user@ec2-107-20-68-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user"
```

the $1 is there to specify the file i want to transfer over. However this is not working and giving me an error:

```
scp: /home/ec2-user: not a regular file
```

This does not happen when I execute this command manually passing in any file for $1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BASH FAQ entry #80: ["How can I make an alias that takes an argument?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately BASH aliases are kind of like find-and-replace -- they're not very powerful for the sort of task you describe. I would suggest using, instead, a script file and placing it in an executable directory; something like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -i keys/aws.pem $1 ec2-user@ec2-107-20-68-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user
```

Then, given that it has the name `loudie-scp` you could call it like so:

```
loudie-scp <parameter>
```

Comment: No reason to make it a whole script, a function works quite as well and is much lighter-weight.

Comment: @Kevin I ended up making a function.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure Ignacio's link will explain, an alias does nothing more than textually expand the alias to its value. It does not take arguments, you need to use a function for that.